# Setting value of input programmatically will have "\" in it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to copy a json string to the clipborad:

```
export const copyToClipboard = () => {
    const text = '{ "name": "hello"}';
    const selBox = document.createElement('input');
    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox.style.left = '0';
    selBox.style.top = '0';
    selBox.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox.value = JSON.stringify(text);
    console.log(text);
    console.log(selBox.value);
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);
};
```

The problem is, the value from `selBox` has the character `\` in it.

The logs look like this:

`{ "name": "hello"}` This is the `text`

`"{ \"name\": \"hello\"}"` This is the value of `selBox`

Why is that happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `text` is already a string so there is no need for `JSON.stringify()`